# What were the original techniques used to study CAM (Crassulacean acid metabolism) plants? Who first employed these methods?

Tags: biology

In biology and botany, there is extensive research concerning the nature of different plant types and their methods of respiration and nutrient intake.

How were [CAM (Crassulacean Acid Metabolism) plants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crassulacean_acid_metabolism) first studied? Who first developed the methods to observe and study CAM plants, and how did they utilize these methods to discover respiration, chemical properties and other facets that constitute what a CAM plant is?

If there are any links regarding the origins of such methods, please leave an answer below.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could expand the acronym CAM.

Comment: Are the "Historical background" section and references in the linked Wikipedia article not enough?